# Removing Extra Spacing Between Lines - Website Code

Tags: css, html-email

I'm trying to build a table in my email host for a future marketing email and I'm so darn close to finishing it up - but there's one last item that's stumping me. I'm trying to find a way to remove the extra spacing between the bullets - I know the text itself is single spaced like I want, but I don't want there to be double spacing of sorts between text items or bullets. Is there a small bit of code I can add into the below to adjust spacing between bullets to single or perhaps 1.5x?

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top"><span style="line-height:1"><img height="30" 
src="https://i.postimg.cc/52RGgKNg/63724-MYK-PP-Email-Announcement-02.png
" width="30" /></span></td>
      <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><span style="line-height:normal"><span style="font:14px arsenal"><span 
style="color:#86c8c5">Cruelty Free</span></span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top"><span style="line-height:1"><img height="30" 
src="https://i.postimg.cc/52RGgKNg/63724-MYK-PP-Email-Announcement-02.png
" width="30" /></span></td>
      <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><span style="line-height:normal"><span style="font:14px arsenal"><span 
style="color:#86c8c5">Vegan Friendly</span></span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top"><span style="line-height:1"><img height="30" 
src="https://i.postimg.cc/52RGgKNg/63724-MYK-PP-Email-Announcement-02.png
" width="30" /></span></td>
      <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><span style="line-height:1"><span style="font:14px arsenal"><span 
style="color:#86c8c5">Refillable Bottle for Life</span></span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top"><span style="line-height:1"><img height="30" 
src="https://i.postimg.cc/52RGgKNg/63724-MYK-PP-Email-Announcement-02.png
" width="30" /></span></td>
      <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><span style="line-height:1"><span style="font:14px arsenal"><span 
style="color:#86c8c5">Soothing Yuzu and<br />
      Rice Water Formula</span></span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```